# Cuda, CuDNN installed But Tensorflow can't use the GPU

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, gpu, cudnn

My system is Ubuntu 14.04 on EC2.:

```
nvidia-smi
Sun Oct  2 13:35:28 2016       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 352.63     Driver Version: 352.63         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GRID K520           Off  | 0000:00:03.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   37C    P0    35W / 125W |     11MiB /  4095MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-990:~$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

I Installed CUDA 7.5 and CuDNN 5.1.

I have the proper files in /usr/local/local/lib64 and include folders.

Tensorflow line gives nothing:

```
    sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))

>>> sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
Device mapping: no known devices.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:252] Device mapping:

>>>
```

Please help (Thanks a lot :)).

Comment: @talonmies existing solutions are not working, I have checked the path variables again and again.

Comment: You appear to have a working CUDA installation. Therefore this'd question is a tensorflow configuration issue and nothing to do with CUDA  programming. That is why I recovered the tag.

Comment: @talonmies yes, thats what i thought, there must be some problem in linking or path...like that. could you suggest anything i could try? thanks.

Comment: I had same problem. I recommend you to check **Tensorflow compatibility** with CUDA/cuDNN/Python from [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you build  tensorflow?

If you did it with bazel did you add correctly --config=cuda?

If you installed it with pip did you took correctly the one with gpu enable?

EDIT:

You can see here how to install with pip:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation

You need to take the one with binary compatible with gpu:

```
# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled, Python 2.7
# Requires CUDA toolkit 7.5 and CuDNN v5. For other versions, see "Install from sources" below.
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

# Mac OS X, GPU enabled, Python 2.7:
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-py2-none-any.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled, Python 3.4
# Requires CUDA toolkit 7.5 and CuDNN v5. For other versions, see "Install from sources" below.
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled, Python 3.5
# Requires CUDA toolkit 7.5 and CuDNN v5. For other versions, see "Install from sources" below.
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl

# Mac OS X, GPU enabled, Python 3.4 or 3.5:
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-py3-none-any.whl
```

then install tensorflow:

```
# Python 2
$ sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL

# Python 3
$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

Comment: what is the pip option for gpu? I didn't see any gpu command alonside pip. Please let me know if there is any command, I will mark it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer, you can check it. I hope it helps. No real option just need take theright binary.